# How to check if an integer is within a range?

Tags: php, int, range

Is there a way to test a range without doing this redundant code:

```
if ($int>$min && $int<$max)
```

?

Like a function:

```
function testRange($int,$min,$max){
    return ($min<$int && $int<$max);
}
```

usage:

```
if (testRange($int,$min,$max))
```

?

Does PHP have such built-in function? Or any other way to do it?

Comment: There is a horrible way using `in_array()` and `range()`. Other than that, I don't think there is one

Comment: Why would you call that "redundant code" ? It is what has to be evaluated, isn't it?

Comment: @Pekka - agreed, not resource friendly, but *is* another option. :)

Comment: Indeed. Which bit of that original fast, readable code is redundant, exactly? And who would know just reading a call to your testRange() whether testRange(1, 1, 2) would be true or false?

Comment: I think what he's referring to is having to specify the same variable in the condition twice.  While I agree that a language construct that lets you say `if($int between $min and $max)` would be nice, I'm afraid the only language I've seen do that is SQL.

Comment: Is of course redundant because in the if you have to type twice the same var name ($int) introducing more possibilities to make errors, and more changes in case of refactor (@wes p: you are exactly right). and @anyonoums downvoter: explain in the comment why you are downvoting this simple question.

Comment: @Wes P, would `$int between $min and $max` be the same as `$int > $min && $int < $max`, `$int >= $min && $int < $max`, `$int > $min && $int <= $max` or `$int >= $min && $int <= $max`?

Comment: @Yes Personally, I'd argue that using a function introduces more possibilities to make errors -- there's chance of getting your parameters in the wrong order, for example. Plus, would you want to add another function, to compare ($int >= $min && $int <= $max), another very common comparison? I suppose if you're writing this particular code over and over again, a function is the way to go if you don't mind the overhead, but yes, you'll have to roll your own, as there's not one built-in in PHP. (I am not, by the way, the anonymous downvoter, though, just interested in talking things over ;) )

Comment: @yes123, for a language to have such operator, it should be clearly stated what it does. E.g., Wes P mentioned SQL which has `expr between min and max` operator, but it works differently from what you're looking for, so even if PHP had it, it would not work for you in this particular case.

Comment: @WesP: Also Python: `if 5<n<9:`. Even better than `between`. Don't try this in more traditional languages though - at best would be compiled as `(int)(5<n)<9`. Also if n is an expression then it is evaluated only once.

Comment: Similar: [How to check if an integer is within a range of numbers in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4684023/55075)

Comment: Ideally, what I would like (and am disappointed that it's lacking in pretty much every language I've encountered) is a language construct that mimics mathematics in this regard. 

 `$x > 0 && $x < 10` => `0 < $x < 10`

Comment: I think you need `>=` and `<=` for checking a range. Then `testRange(0, 0, 100) == true`

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Tested your 3 ways with a 1000000-times-loop.

t1_test1: `($val >= $min && $val <= $max)`: 0.3823 ms

t2_test2: `(in_array($val, range($min, $max))`: 9.3301 ms

t3_test3: `(max(min($var, $max), $min) == $val)`:   0.7272 ms

T1 was fastest, it was basicly this:

```
function t1($val, $min, $max) {
  return ($val >= $min && $val <= $max);
}
```

Comment: That's what I expected :)

Comment: Nice! as i need it to tell me whether true or false, i added the following: `function t1($val, $min, $max) {
  if ($val >= $min && $val <= $max) {return true;} else {return false;}
}`

Comment: @pathros the above function already returns `true` or `false`, no need to write additional code

Comment: It's also unnecessary to use brackets. "return $val >= $min && $val <= $max;" is enough.

Comment: I don't think the question is asking about performance. Other languages have native operators for this and I think that's what OP was looking for.

Comment: Another test with this variant (filter_var) would still be interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684023/how-to-check-if-an-integer-is-within-a-range-of-numbers-in-php

Answer (score 48):

I don't think you'll get a better way than your function.

It is clean, easy to follow and understand, and returns the result of the condition (no `return (...) ? true : false` mess).

Comment: What is this "return mess" that you speak of? Can you elaborate? Provide an example of bad vs good practice? Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

There is no builtin function, but you can easily achieve it by calling the functions `min()` and `max()` appropriately.

```
// Limit integer between 1 and 100000
$var = max(min($var, 100000), 1);
```

Comment: This is very interesting. However, I wouldn't use it purely for the sake of readibility.

Comment: The idea is really interesting as said above, but it's difficult to read and it calls two function that can be avoided.

Answer (score 12):

Most of the given examples assume that for the test range [$a..$b],  $a <= $b, i.e. the range extremes are in lower - higher order and most assume that all are integer numbers.
But I needed a function to test if $n was between $a and $b, as described here:

```
Check if $n is between $a and $b even if:
    $a < $b  
    $a > $b
    $a = $b

All numbers can be real, not only integer.
```

There is an easy way to test.
I base the test it in the fact that `($n-$a)` and `($n-$b)` have different signs when $n is between $a and $b, and the same sign when $n is outside the $a..$b range.
This function is valid for testing increasing, decreasing, positive and negative numbers, not limited to test only integer numbers.

```
function between($n, $a, $b)
{
    return (($a==$n)&&($b==$n))? true : ($n-$a)*($n-$b)<0;
}
```

Comment: This is nice. Do note that if there's a chance that $n, $a and $b happen to be the same number, this function will return false while most others would return true.

Comment: Thanks @bksunday for your comment. I have added treatment of this case to the code.

Comment: I have to add a precision to @bksunday comment and my answer. Interval can be open interval or closed interval. Open intervals don't include limits while closed ones do include them. As a consequence, in the case of the original question from dynamic, it was an open interval and therefore when $a=$b=$n it should return false as it was my original function, or even easier: An open interval ($a, $b)  with $a=$b is an empty set.

Comment: if $n=0, and $a=0 and $b=1, this functionjs returns FALSE. Why? 0 is in range (between 0 and 1), so should return TRUE

Answer (score 9):

I'm not able to comment (not enough reputation) so I'll amend Luis Rosety's answer here:

```
function between($n, $a, $b) {
    return ($n-$a)*($n-$b) <= 0;
}
```

This function works also in cases where n == a or n == b.

Proof:
Let n belong to range [a,b], where [a,b] is a subset of real numbers.

Now a <= n <= b. Then n-a >= 0 and n-b <= 0. That means that (n-a)*(n-b) <= 0.

Case b <= n <= a works similarly.

Comment: Interval type (open or closed) is important. Open interval exclude limits while closed one do include limits. Please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)

Comment: Well sure, when working with floating-point numbers, but when working with integers (as per the question) that's irrelevant. Keep in mind that (a,b) is effectively [a+1, b-1] with all integers a and b.

Comment: best answer for me

Answer (score 3):

There's `filter_var()` as well and it's **the native function which checks range**. It doesn't give exactly what you want (never returns true), but with "cheat" we can change it.

I don't think it's a good code as for readability, but I show it's as a possibility:

```
return (filter_var($someNumber, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, ['options' => ['min_range' => $min, 'max_range' => $max]]) !== false)
```

Just fill `$someNumber`, `$min` and `$max`. `filter_var` with that filter returns either boolean false when number is outside range or the number itself when it's within range. The expression (`!== false`) makes function return true, when number is within range.

If you want to shorten it somehow, remember about type casting. If you would use `!=` it would be false for number 0 within range -5; +5 (while it should be true). The same would happen if you would use type casting (`(bool)`).

```
// EXAMPLE OF WRONG USE, GIVES WRONG RESULTS WITH "0"
(bool)filter_var($someNumber, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, ['options' => ['min_range' => $min, 'max_range' => $max]])
if (filter_var($someNumber, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, ['options' => ['min_range' => $min, 'max_range' => $max]])) ...
```

Imagine that (from other answer):

```
if(in_array($userScore, range(-5, 5))) echo 'your score is correct'; else echo 'incorrect, enter again';
```

If user would write empty value (`$userScore = ''`) it would be correct, as `in_array` is set here for default, non-strict more and that means that range creates `0` as well, and `'' == 0` (non-strict), but `'' !== 0` (if you would use strict mode). It's easy to miss such things and that's why I wrote a bit about that. **I was learned that strict operators are default, and programmer could use non-strict only in special cases**. I think it's a good lesson. Most examples here would fail in some cases because non-strict checking.

Still I like filter_var and you can use above (or below if I'd got so "upped" ;)) functions and make your own callback which you would use as `FILTER_CALLBACK` filter. You could return bool or even add `openRange` parameter. And other good point: you can use [other functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php), e.g. checking range of every number of array or POST/GET values. That's really powerful tool.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it using `in_array()` combined with `range()`

```
if (in_array($value, range($min, $max))) {
    // Value is in range
}
```

*Note* As has been pointed out in the comments however, this is not exactly a great solution if you are focussed on performance. Generating an array (escpecially with larger ranges) will slow down the execution.

Comment: @Yukulélé And the question was: How to check if an INTEGER is within a range?

Comment: See my answer to Nebuloasar.

Comment: The idea is interesting and readable, but there is poor performance using this way.

Comment: I think it's a good choice, thanks for your comprehension. So, I removed my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Using comparison operators is way, way faster than calling any function. I'm not 100% sure if this exists, but I think it doesn't.

Comment: Indeed using comparison operators is faster than calling a function, because functions are slow in PHP. On other hand, it's only one independant function that avoid to repeat the operators every time. A middle way could be Macro in some other languages like C, C++ or Rust. But PHP doesn't have this feature nor a built-in function 'between', so to use a function it's mandatory to create the function, or to use 'filter_var' as said in an answer even if in this case 'filter_var' is not very convenient to write.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility (not a solution) :

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT $value BETWEEN $min and $max as test")->fetch_object()->test;
```

Comment: If you use this, please be aware that it is IMPERATIVE that you check `$value`, `$min` and `$max` for type. If one of them can be an arbitrary string (worst case from the user), this is an SQL injection hazard and you are gonna get hacked.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expansion on the answer provided by @Mark Paspirgilis, allows for selectable inclusion and returns a Boolean response.

```
public function between($p_value, $p_min, $p_max, $p_inclusive=0) {
  ## 0 = all inclusive; -1 = left inclusive; 1 = right inclusive
  if ($p_inclusive == -1) {
    return (bool)($p_value >= $p_min && $p_value < $p_max);
  }
  else if ($p_inclusive == 1) {
    return (bool)($p_value > $p_min && $p_value <= $p_max);
  }
  else {
    return (bool)($p_value >= $p_min && $p_value <= $p_max);
  }
} # END FUNCTION between
```