# How to test if $value is $num +-3

Tags: php, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php if integer between a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029409/php-if-integer-between-a-range)

Let's say `$num = 5;` How do I test if `$value` is anything in between +-3 of $num. In other words, how can I test if `$value` is equal to any of these values `2,3,4 5 6,7,8`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two possible ways to do it:

1. `$num - 3 <= $value && value <= $num + 3`
2. `abs($num - $value) <= 3`

Answer (score 2):

```
$mid = 5;
$range = 3;
$inRange = ($myval>=$mid-$range && $myval<=$mid+$range) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

**UPDATE**
I started throwin' out bass, she started throwin' back mid-range.

Comment: Nobody else appreciated my **sweet** unintentional Biz Markie reference, I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($num - 3 <= $value && $value <= $num + 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($value<=$num+3 && $value>=$num-3)
    echo "$value is between +-3 of $num";
else
    echo "$value is outside +-3 of $num";
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$dif1 = $num - 3;
$dif2 = $num + 3;

if($dif1 <= $value){
       if($dif2 <= $value){
              echo "Your number in between +-3";
       }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing big logic in this if you know the $num value take two variable $min and $max

set `$min = $num - 3`

set `$max = $num + 3`

and then with condition check your value..

`$value > $min && $value < $max`