# Optimize if-statement to check values

Tags: php

How can I optimize this if-statement?

```
if ($min && $max && $value && ($min <= $max) && ($min <= $value) && ($value <= $max)) {
    // do anything
}
```

What it should do:

I got three values (min, max and value). First of all, all values should be != 0. Second, min <= value <= max.

Valid:

```
min = 1; max = 3; value = 2;
min = 2; max = 2; value = 2;
```

Comment: I don't see much need to optimize this, as it is composed of simple boolean comparisons. It's readable and clear in its current form.

Comment: (edited comment about zero values - you already mention that and address it correctly)

Comment: You can remove the check for `($min <= $max)`, as you are indirectly checking for this with `($min <= $value) && ($value <= $max)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought this statement is a little bit long.

Comment: Whenever you feel an `if` condition chain gets too long, a function can make sense; see also [if integer between a range?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5029409)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this:

```
if ( 0 < $min && $min <= $value && $value <= $max ){
    echo 'good';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
if(isset($min , $max , $value ) && ($min <= $value) && ($value <= $max)){
//Insert your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this prevents any value from being a 0 and makes sure value is inside the min and max range.

```
if ( ( $min > 0 && $max >= $min ) && ( $value >= $min && $value <= $max ) ) {
  echo "Good";
} else {
  echo "Bad";
}
```