# PHP: How to know if number is in a interval of int?

Tags: php, int, set

I have a variable of int type called `myNumber` and I need to know if it is in the interval [100, 200].

Example:

```
if (myNumber in (100, 200)) {
    echo 'Yes';
}
```

I wonder if PHP has a `in` function or similar.

Comment: You could simply write one yourself. `return $input >= $left && $input <= $right`

Comment: if (myNumber > 100 && myNumber < 200) is the fastest way.

Comment: google's first result when searching for `php between` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029409/how-to-check-if-an-integer-is-within-a-range

Comment: No one answered `$range = [100,200]; if($number >= $range[0] && $number <= $range[1])`  or `$min` `$max`  must be slacking....  Range does have the benefit of using a `step` other then one.  etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Php does not have it, but you can create it like this example.

```
function in($number,$min,$max){
    if($number >= $min and $number <= $max){
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range` and `in_array` function

```
<?php
$x = 150;
if ( in_array($x, range(100,200)) ) {
    echo 'Number '.$x.' is in range';
}
else
{
    echo 'Number '.$x.' is not in range';
}

?>
```

Also, You can create your own function in php for the same

```
<?php
$x = 150;

function in_range($x)
{
    if ( in_array($x, range(100,200)) ) 
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

$result = in_range($x);

?>
```

To know more details you can read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

Comment: the range() will kill performance. What if the numbers are 1, 100000, that means you create a massive array that will be looped to find a matching number. Not good...