# if row equals 2 thru 10 - VERY EASY PHP

Tags: php

Sorry that I can't find the answer through google - But I know this has got to be really easy.

I have a code like this

```
if ($row == 1)
```

I also want something that states if $row equals 2 through 10 then do this... What is the correct php for this? Thank you.

Comment: `if ($row >= 2 && $row <= 10)` Or if you're feeling complex, `if (in_array($row, range(2,10))`

Comment: Review the [PHP manual on comparison operators.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. Both worked like a charm!

Comment: Thank you I was gonna ask for a link to some kind of document. Need to learn this so I'm not back here with another beginner question... but I will be. lol

Comment: possible duplicate of [php if integer is in a range of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684023/php-if-integer-is-in-a-range-of-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the comment on the OP:

> `if ($row >= 2 && $row <= 10)`Or if you're feeling complex, `if (in_array($row, range(2,10))`
>   – [Michael 1 min ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897333/if-row-equals-2-thru-10-very-easy-php/9897384#comment12626429_9897333)

---

> Missed the [all-important documentation link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) from the subsequent comment.
>   – [Michael 6 secs ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897333/if-row-equals-2-thru-10-very-easy-php/9897384#comment12626530_9897384)

Comment: Missed the all-important documentation link from the subsequent comment.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you only want it to match for integers (i.e. 2, 3, 4 etc and not 2.2, 3.5232 etc). If so, then you can use:

```
if (ctype_digit($row) && $row > 0 && $row < 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check it falls within a range

```
If ($row >= 2 && $row <= 10)
```